# Font scaling issues in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-4.0

I'm currently developing an application in WPF (.NET 4 / VS 2010) and I'm experiencing issues related to font scaling.

In short, the text in my application is often deformed or doesn't represent what it should look like "typically".

You can see an example of the problem here, taken from a control using the Helvetica Neue LT Pro font, at a size of 12:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kx6wm.jpg

Here's another example, with a font size of 9:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGFAt.jpg

I tried changing the text formatting mode as suggered (i.e.: TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"), but that didn't help.

Is there anything that I can do to help improve the font rendering ? Are there a set of fonts that are optimized for WPF that scale well ?

Should I just stick with "ClearType" fonts ?

Comment: Are you developing on any system other than a real local machine?  i.e. are you developing on a VM, or over RDP, or through Citrix etc?  I have experienced those text artifacts when running things on remote or VM machines and I am pretty sure it has to do with the Generic Software graphics rendering.

Comment: I'm developing on a real local machine actually, hence why I'm pretty perplexed. From what I read, .Net 4 had various improvements related to font renderings. Thanks for the tip regarding VMs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out the recommendations for font clarity in WPF listed here: http://windowsclient.net/wpf/white-papers/wpftextclarity.aspx

Specifically, it looks like you might be seeing the one described under the "Aliasing Text" header.

Comment: Thanks; I also stumbled on that page while researching a solution, and ClearType is already enabled on my monitor. I tried the same application on another desktop (with ClearType enabled), and the same problem surfaced. The only recommendation given is to increase the font size, but unfortunately not all controls can have text displayed in a font large enough to hold the text.

Comment: How about this one then: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/text/archive/2010/01/15/cleartypehint.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link, it unfortunately didn't resolve the problem. I also noticed just now that it appears only with fonts in bold. Weird...